# How do I do an animated imageView in appcelerator?

Tags: appcelerator, animated-gif

```
  loader_array = [];
  for (var i=1; i <= 24; i++) {
    loader_array.push('/images/system/block_loaders/' + i + '.png');
  };

  var loadingSpinner = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    images: loader_array,
    duration: 100,
    repeatCount: 100,
    opacity: 0.5
  });
  self.add(loadingSpinner);
```

When I do that, I get nothing. But if I do a single image from that set and use `image` instead of `images`, it works fine. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Try This One if Works](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/68971/does-imageview-support-gif-file)
answered by brian kurzius

Answer (score 1):

Android or iOS?

If android and set duration, you have called start method to animate.